# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when installing Github for Windows

Tags: clickonce, github-for-windows

I'm trying to install GitHub for Windows and I get the following error message:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.0.6002.131072 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18052
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18052 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [04/12/2013 08:29:27] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [04/12/2013 08:29:27] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.GetAssemblyManifest(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetAssemblyManifest(DefinitionIdentity asmId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Does anyone understand what is causing this?

Comment: "Does anyone understand what is causing this?" It is fine that we have a solution but I would like to understand the problem. I'm experiencing the same problem within our company. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here are two solutions for you to try, the second manual delete worked for me. (Also make sure  you runt he installer with admin privileges.

Its likely to be a problem with the ClickOnce Application Cache. Could you try the following in order to clear the cache

> 1. Hold down the `Windows` key and type `R`.
> 2. Type in `rundll32 %SystemRoot%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache` in the run dialog and hit `Enter`.
>
> Then try installing the application.
>
> If that doesn't work, there's a more manual approach to ensuring the cache is cleared - you can delete the ClickOnce Application folder.
>
> - On `Windows Vista` or higher, this will be the `%LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0` directory.
> - On `Windows XP` this will be the `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Apps\2.0` directory.

Note that this path may be in a different language if you're using a non-English version of Windows.

Comment: hi! I tried above methods. But it did not work for me.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani try repeating both several times and rebooting. this helped me

Comment: The manual approach of deleting all folders inside %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Apps\2.0 worked for me. I was then able to uninstall the clickonce app from Add/Remove Programs and reinstall. Thanks.

Comment: Can I damage other installed application when deleting %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0   directory?

Comment: Anyone can tell me why this problem occurs? Is this issue is related to deployment?

Comment: only the manual solution worked for me on windows 10

Answer (score 14):

deleting %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0 folder works fine

Comment: careful that this will delete *all* clickonce apps, not just the one with an issue