# Clickonce - The referenced assembly is not installed on your system

Tags: clickonce

Some of my users are unable to launch a clickonce application from our website, while others can.  We are getting a message `The referenced assembly is not installed on your system` however from the log I have not a clue as to what assembly they are talking about.  How can I track this down?

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://myapp.example.com/MyDir/MyApp.application?t7ZqWrTkOp%2b1COP7P1YeWKiZ%2f0ifBW0SdoYOMhhSBBjOatTy9WDvq2fZcAadpm2Vdm9nB%2bGoZlAvTYKIxhVmaymMxZungC1lfuk2%2bp4JstCHKd5ospkLHUwMF17h1o%2f1HOeMya9eQtztA6DswY84VUjqUJ0y%2bqvX1iUvnWueL2SeLYEikPCHLKLmlKgW2H2qP%2f%2fwPMvWFub2zcEwB%2bHwqdaPhQCf8qse
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Deployment Provider url     : http://myapp.example.com/MyDir/MyApp.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Application url         : http://myapp.example.com/MyDir/MyApp.exe.manifest
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : MyApp-MySite.app, Version=5.40.14.4435, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86
    Application Identity        : MyApp-MySite.exe, Version=5.40.14.4435, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://myapp.example.com/MyDir/MyApp.application?t7ZqWrTkOp%2b1COP7P1YeWKiZ%2f0ifBW0SdoYOMhhSBBjOatTy9WDvq2fZcAadpm2Vdm9nB%2bGoZlAvTYKIxhVmaymMxZungC1lfuk2%2bp4JstCHKd5ospkLHUwMF17h1o%2f1HOeMya9eQtztA6DswY84VUjqUJ0y%2bqvX1iUvnWueL2SeLYEikPCHLKLmlKgW2H2qP%2f%2fwPMvWFub2zcEwB%2bHwqdaPhQCf8qse resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:37 PM] : Activation of http://myapp.example.com/MyDir/MyApp.application?t7ZqWrTkOp%2b1COP7P1YeWKiZ%2f0ifBW0SdoYOMhhSBBjOatTy9WDvq2fZcAadpm2Vdm9nB%2bGoZlAvTYKIxhVmaymMxZungC1lfuk2%2bp4JstCHKd5ospkLHUwMF17h1o%2f1HOeMya9eQtztA6DswY84VUjqUJ0y%2bqvX1iUvnWueL2SeLYEikPCHLKLmlKgW2H2qP%2f%2fwPMvWFub2zcEwB%2bHwqdaPhQCf8qse has started.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:38 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:38 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:38 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:40 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:40 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:45 PM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:45 PM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2/27/2017 2:41:45 PM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.GetAssemblyManifest(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetAssemblyManifest(DefinitionIdentity asmId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.CollectCrossGroupApplications(Uri codebaseUri, DefinitionIdentity deploymentIdentity, Boolean& identityGroupFound, Boolean& locationGroupFound, String& identityGroupProductName)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370490/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-when-installing-github-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

A good point to start your investigation is the `Application Files` dialog on the `Publish` tab of the project settings. Look for assemblies that are marked as `Prerequisite` in the `Publish Status` column.

Another object of investigation could be the application manifest. You'll find the file named `[application name].exe.manifest` next to the application's executable in the publishing folder. Search for `dependentAssembly` nodes with `dependencyType` attribute set to `preRequisite`.