# Latest build of a ClickOnce WPF app refuses to activate during a local install on one particular machine

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, windows-11

**Introduction:**
We have 3 relevant test servers:
   `name    OS             version         .NET         CLR`            
   `TS1     Win7 Pro SP1   6.1.7601.65536   4.5.51209   4.0.30319.34209`
   `TS2     Wsrv2008r2 SP1 6.1.7601.65536   4.8.03761   4.0.30319.42000`
   `TS3     W11 Pro (22H2) 10.0.22621.0     4.8.09032   4.0.30319.42000`

Our app-suite consists of Win-services and interactive apps.  The latter are deployed as ClickOnce packages to IIS.
Testing starts on app-server with CO apps downloaded and installed locally (upgrading previous versions).

Let's name the two CO WPF-apps **A** and **B**, followed by **1** (previous build) or **2** (latest build).
Changes in build 2 to both A and B involved UI behavior only.  References and dependencies were not touched, projects were not edited, no new files, no deletions.  Build procedure is always the same (by a script).  A and B are similar in nature and reference same libraries with 1 exception:  A uses `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

**Observations:**

1. A2 deployed to TS3 *has a problem* (see below) downloading and installing locally for admin user.
2. A2 deployed to TS1 has *exactly the same problem* downloading and installing to TS3 for admin user.
3. A2 deployed to TS1 downloads and installs perfectly fine locally for admin user.
4. A2 deployed to TS3 downloads and installs on TS1 or TS2 perfectly fine locally for admin user.
5. B1 and B2 download and install any which way you want - from either test servers to any

A2 fails activation phase (see below) on TS3, **but only on TS3**.  B2 is happy on any test machine.
The failure occures *before* the user is asked if an app from unknown publisher should be installed (we use self-signed test certificates, generated by VisualStudio for signing ClickOnce deployments):

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.22621.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.8.9139.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_B
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.22621.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://desktop-vtq5f2f/AppAch/client/AppAcw.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://desktop-vtq5f2f/AppAch/client/AppAcw.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [3/1/2023 12:39:54 PM] : Activation of http://desktop-vtq5f2f/AppAch/client/AppAcw.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [3/1/2023 12:40:03 PM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.GetAssemblyManifest(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetAssemblyManifestFromStore(DefinitionIdentity asmId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetAssemblyManifestWithRetry(DefinitionIdentity asmId, TimeSpan retryInterval, Int32 maxRetryCount)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Logical conclusion is:  **smth's wrong with TS3**, right?  But *what*, and *how do I figure it out*?

I searched for `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll` on TS3:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET>dir /s System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
Directory of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089
  05/06/2022  22:20  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll  290,720 bytes
Directory of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
  05/06/2022  22:20  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll  290,720 bytes
Directory of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
  05/06/2022  22:20  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll  290,720 bytes
```

**A1 downloads and installs just fine.  A2, folder-xcopied to TS3, runs without any problems**.
My conclusion is:  nothing is missing on TS3 from referenced libraries, so the problem must be specific to installation.

For the love of all, Microsoft, **why omit the name of offending file from the log?!**  It would be so helpful!
Windows Event Log does not have any trace of my multiple attempts, so it is of no use.

**Search of similar errors:**
Googling `+System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 0x800736B3` brought me to the following:

- [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-update-0x800736b3/85a56759-67a7-4fe5-bb66-47fe9d03924c) - identifies 0x800736b3 as `ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND` from <winerror.h>
- [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88204db3-7c22-44c9-8d72-98c0ad2a1f3c/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x800736b3) - similar error described with little detail and no answers - not useful
- [clickonce-the-referenced-assembly-is-not-installed-on-your-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510633/) - but no changes to publishing [or build] process, same files are listed in Prerequisites, besides same package installs on other machines
- [system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-when-installing-github-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370490/) -   probably the best advice, which i already knew:  clean ClickOnce cache

As expected, `rundll32 %SystemRoot%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache` removed all files and most subfolders under `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`.  I followed with a reboot of TS3, the error is still thrown.
`mage.exe -cc` did not make a difference.

`Side-by-side assembly` (*SxS, what a gem!*) hints at something in the system, not the app, but **why did it never occur before**, and **why does it affect one app but not the other?**
Color me **puzzled**!  Does anybody have a clue?  Where should i dig?

Answer (score 0):

Should've tried that earlier, but who knew that m$'s tools for cleaning CO cache fail so miserably?  They remove files, but leave folders, which somehow lock up subsequent attempts..

As mentioned by @Nemo [in comment to accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384382/803920), "The manual approach of deleting **all folders** inside `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Apps\2.0` worked".
In my case it was `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`.

Didn't need to go to extent of deleting the whole `\2.0` folder, suggested by @Erdem in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24133430/803920).

And yes, whichever way **cleaning ClickOnce cache removes all CO apps** - *for this user*.